# How to partclone an NTFS partition to a smaller disk without having space for the full image

Tags: linux, hard-drive, backup, restore, partition-copy

Every now and then I have got the following problem:

A disk fails and the replacement disk is smaller. The data often easily fits the smaller disk, but partclone simply does not shrink the filesystem to match the smaller partition size.

You can simply image the whole disk onto your temporary drive then shrink. But if there is not enough space?

Comment: maybe try ntfsclone?

Comment: "A disk fails" <- there's your problem. Otherwise just shrink the partition on the source disk before copying. Then if you really want you can expand the partition on the source disk again. I would just use the Gparted live disk from https://gparted.sourceforge.io/

Comment: Well, I prefer not to mess with the source drive without having a backup. But of course you could do a standard backup with partclone first.

Answer (score 4):

*Does not work yet from point 16 on. Maybe because there was a stale loop device I did not delete.*

### `partclone` raw dump into sparse image

**This solution is dangerous to your data. Only try if you understand what you are doing and are familiar with `dd` and devices. I won't be responsible for any data loss.**

Before we start:

- Do not use this procedure to mirror a disk that is physically damaged because

  - `partclone` needs a healthy filesystem to work on
  - this procedure is far more complex than doing `dd` so you probably have to repeat it several times until you succeed - bringing more strain on the broken disk
  - for broken disks you should use `safecopy` instead because `dd` aborts on bad sectors
- You need up to **2 x data-size free space** on your temporary drive.
- I will enter `sdXX` for any command that might destroy data if you forgot to customize the command. This does not deal with loops, so be sure to **NOT use any other loop devices** during the following process to avoid accidentally overriding valuable data.
- If you fail somewhere and delete the image, be sure to first unmount anything pointing to it, then remove the loop devices: `kpartx -dv <image>`. **It may cause major problems if you use wrong loop devices!** I believe my problem is caused by a stale loop device...
- Find fixes for common problems at the end of this answer.

Let's go

1. get the disk size of your source disk

   ```
   sudo fdisk -l /dev/sda
   output: Disk /dev/sda: 465,8 GiB, 500107862016 bytes, 976773168 sectors
   ```
2. read the original partition layout into image

   ```
   sudo dd if=/dev/sda of=sparse.img bs=1M count=1
   ```
3. fill the image with "nothing" up to the above size. - *This will **not** take any space on disk.*

   ```
   sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=sparse.img bs=1 count=0 seek=500107862016
   ```
4. check there are no other loop-devices active - *if the output is not empty, see trouble shooting section*

   ```
   losetup -l -a
   ```
5. check if partition layout is the same as source drive

   ```
   fdisk -l sparse.img
   ```
6. create loop devices for access of the partitions in the image

   ```
   sudo kpartx -av sparse.img 
   output: add map loop0p1 (253:0): 0 976771072 linear 7:2 2048
   ```
7. read the data into the image using `partclone` - *this will increase space usage by "data size" plus "overhead".*

   ```
   sudo partclone.ntfs -s /dev/sda1 -o /dev/mapper/loop0p1 -b -L sparse.log
   ```
8. remove source drive to keep it save
9. shrink using `gparted` - *should be at least 10% smaller than target drive*

   - create links because `gparted` does not understand the devs `kpartx` created.

     ```
     ln -s /dev/mapper/loop0p1 sparse.img1
     ```
   - use `gparted` to shrink the partition

     ```
     sudo gparted sparse.img
     ```
10. alternatively you can shrink using `ntfsresize` but you have to shrink the partition, too afterwards.

    - get min size

      ```
      sudo ntfsresize -i /dev/mapper/loop0p1
      ```
    - test resize

      ```
      sudo ntfsresize -n -s 100G /dev/mapper/loop0p1
      ```
    - real resize - *this will increase space usage by up to "data size"*

      ```
      sudo ntfsresize -s 100G /dev/mapper/loop0p1
      ```
    - TODO: shrink partition
11. *(unnecessary because shrinked not enlarged?)* delete and recreate the loop devices because partition size changed

    ```
    sudo kpartx -dv sparse.img 
    sudo kpartx -av sparse.img
    ```
12. *(optional) TODO* truncate image
13. check using `ntfsresize` - *for me this gives an OK answer*

    ```
    sudo ntfsresize -i /dev/mapper/loop0p1
    ```
14. insert target drive - **double check you inserted the correct drive**
15. *(does not work because `ntfsresize` marked the fs dirty)* `partclone` the image to the new drive

    ```
    sudo partclone.ntfs -o /dev/sdXX -s /dev/mapper/loop0p1 -b -L restore.log
    ```
16. instead `dd` the image to the new drive - *either do not give a size or be 10% over the shrinked partition size*

    ```
    sudo dd if=sparse.img of=/dev/sdXX
    ```
17. check using `ntfsresize` - **FAILS for me, this should not happen as the image was OK and we created an identical copy of the image!!!**

    ```
    sudo ntfsresize -i /dev/sda1
    ```
18. delete loop devices

    ```
    sudo kpartx -dv sparse.img
    ```
19. delete any loop devices that were not cleanly removed - *if still some persist, either reboot or search the web on this.*

    ```
    sudo losetup -D
    ```
20. Finally you should try booting the disk then run Windows `chkdsk / f`. After that use `gparted` to expand the partition to it's full size.

### Troubleshooting:

- If `ntfsresize` or `gparted` cannot access the image: exec `chkdsk /f` from windows on the source disk. Do NOT use `ntfsfix`. *Any NTFS checker for Linux?*
- If `kpartx` cannot create the loop devices: check with `losetup` and delete unused ones.
- If you want to get rid of obsolete loop devices delete with `sudo losetup -d` or search the web.

Comment: With ubuntu, I was able to create the image with losetup -P -v /dev/loop0 sparse.img
mkfs.ext4 /dev/loop0p1... and gparted /dev/loop0 worked!